# Rails: Assets are not rendered correctly in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I've been struggling with this for a few days now - I added bootstrap (and some other gems) to my rails app, but for some reason the appropriate CSS files are not rendering and thus the bootstrap styles are not showing up.

Here are the relevant parts of my files:

`application.html.erb` in `app/views/layouts`:

```
<head>
  <title>Myapp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/twitter/bootstrap/master/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
</head>
```

`application.css` in `app/assets/stylesheets`:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

(There are also plenty more CSS files in this folder, including `bootstrap_and_overrides.css` and `gmaps4rails.css`).

And the server log when I load the page:

```
$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
        SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
        This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
        provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
        cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
        future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

        Called from: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.
[2013-03-11 15:19:32] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-03-11 15:19:32] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-02-24) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
[2013-03-11 15:19:32] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=94815 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-11 15:19:35 -0700
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.8ms)
  Trip Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "trips".* FROM "trips" 
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (62.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 143ms (Views: 141.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

And the source code that actually gets rendered in Chrome:

```
<head>
  <title>Myapp</title>
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="GfG+KCsrNZaChqWvUz/g5RqsdHrXOtumFzHaOjJmFQg=" name="csrf-token" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/twitter/bootstrap/master/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
</head>
```

And my `Gemfile`:

```
gem "bootstrap-sass", '~> 2.3.0.1'
gem "simple_form"

gem 'gmaps4rails'
```

And `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.cache_classes = false

# Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
config.whiny_nils = true

# Show full error reports and disable caching
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

# Don't care if the mailer can't send
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

# Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
config.active_support.deprecation = :log

# Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

# Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

# Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
# with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false

# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true
```

I have the assets pipeline in `config/application.rb` set to true and I haven't changed the debug settings. My `RAILS_ENV` is `development`. As I understand, rails should be compiling and serving all of the CSS files including `boostrap_and_overrides.css.scss` because of the `require_tree .` call. I've run `rake assets:precompile` and `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` multiple times, but I don't think that should matter. Im running ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474).

The REALLY weird thing is that me and my partners on this project have the exact same code (from our github repository), and it works on their local machines but it doen't work on mine. Does anyone have any input at all into what's going on?

Comment: correct, you don't need assets precompile in development(in fact, you might want to remove all files in /public/assets). Can you see the content of the css from source view in Chrome?I had similar problem before where the css links are there but they all empty.

Comment: No, the CSS file that gets rendered in Chrome is empty (which is weird, since it should at least include the `require` comments etc). For what it's worth, the MD5'd file in `public/assets` specified in `manifest.yml` is also empty (but that shouldn't matter in development, right?)

It occurred to me that things might be working for everyone else on my team but not for me because they might have `RAILS_ENV=production`, but I've tried setting mine to production as well, but nothing is configured to serve the assets, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: can you post up your development.rb in config/environments(you said it's not different from others?). I got this error once in production but it was a wrong unicorn setup(not rails issues). It's your local issue for sure.

Comment: you probably want to remove public/assets (or at least ALL of the files in that directory) in development mode, otherwise the rails server will serve those up instead of compiling the files on the fly. I would delete those files and restart the rails server

Comment: Sure, I just updated the post with it. I haven't changed that file, and at any rate it shouldn't matter, since everyone on my team has the same file (since we're pushing it to github), right?

Comment: Also, removing everything from public/assets doesn't change anything, for some reason.

Comment: just noticed something: `Rails 3.2.8 application starting in development` -> you NEED to upgrade rails to 3.2.12 ASAP - see http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/1/8/Rails-3-2-11-3-1-10-3-0-19-and-2-3-15-have-been-released/ AND http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/2/11/SEC-ANN-Rails-3-2-12-3-1-11-and-2-3-17-have-been-released/

Comment: Well shit, I updated rails (to 3.2.12) in response to the above security issues and somehow everything works now. Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same issue in Rails 3.2.6 which disappears when I upgrade to Rails 3.2.15.